# How to center multi line text in a hidden Div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, multiline

I have a issue with centering a paragraph inside of a div that needs to be aligned vertically. They are inside of sliding boxes that are triggered when hovering over an image. Cannot use display: inline-block because it is currently setting it a default state of display: none;.  Please tell me the best way to handle this, I'm sure someone will have a simple solution, that will make me feel stupid.  Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnWeb/rBsLx/13/

Here is the textbox divs css

```
.textbox {
    max-width: 610px;
    height: 155px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(5, 58, 24, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13) 83%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

I have posted this same code before, but I am not aware of the question asking process or etiquette on here, this is not a jquery problem like it was before, it's functionally working the way I need it to, but this time it is the CSS. So I'm reposting it. (pasted previous question below)

[How to handle a hide/show queue with multiple hidden divs smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235097/how-to-handle-a-hide-show-queue-with-multiple-hidden-divs-smoothly)

Comment: do you want to align the textbox to be at the same place every time??? in the middle??

Comment: are you expecting this..http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Fdud6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` on the `.textbox` `div`s. Remove `display: none` and hide them on dom ready when the page loads. Now you will be able to `vertical-align:middle` on the `div` to make it vertically aligned.

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rBsLx/15/**

*CSS*:

```
.textbox {
    max-width: 610px;
    height: 155px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell; /* make it table-cell */
    vertical-align: middle; /* table-cell will allow vertical align */
    ...
}
```

*JS*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".textbox").hide(); // hide the divs initially
    ... // your code
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link may it will help you..

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rBsLx/16/)

```
.textbox {
max-width: 610px;
height: 155px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(5, 58, 24, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13) 83%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)    100%);
border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;

}
```